# Python Webscrape - Selenium 'CLASS_NAME' - 'not' to include all elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

PYTHON - For Webscraping - is there a way to use Selenium to find an element by CLASS_NAME - but **only** return the elements under class name 'xxxx' and not elements under class name 'xxxxyy'.

This code returns **ALL** elements (inclusive) with CLASS_NAME of 'xxxx'.....and includes CLASS_NAME of 'xxxxyy'.

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'xxxx')
```

This is my attempt - which returns nothing.

```
driver.find_elements((By.CLASS_NAME, 'xxxx') and (not(By.CLASS_NAME, 'xxxxyy')))
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use XPath:

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'xxxx') and not(contains(@class, 'xxxxyy'))]")
```